# Asking for help with a riddle

Tags: riddle

"With three, you'll live forever, just two will kill you."

short, but can't seem to come up with anything :/

attribution: part of a private group ARG game, created by one of the group members.

Comment: Hi there! Where did you find this riddle? Attribution is required on this site

Comment: sent to a private ARG group courtesy tbcmahii@protonmail.com

Answer (score 1):

> I think the [Deathly Hallows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magical_objects_in_Harry_Potter#Deathly_Hallows) from *Harry Potter* serve as a solution. Having all three artifacts is said to grant one mastery over life and death, and could very well make you immortal. But having only one of them killed each of three brothers, and having only two of them would probably kill you as well.

Answer (score 0):

A few guesses:

> **Trimesters of a pregnancy?** A baby who grows for all three trimesters before being born has a good chance of being healthy and living, but only two trimesters causes babies to be extremely premature and they will likely die. I'm not sure how living "forever" ties into that though, so this is probably not it...

> **Rule of three in survival?** You can live for three weeks without food, three days without water, and three minutes without oxygen. Obviously only having two minutes of oxygen would kill you. But again, living "forever" doesn't seem to fit this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking it has something to do with

> **THREE** in Spanish - **TRES** (Sounds like **TRACE**) and 
>  **TWO** in Spanish - **DOS** (Sounds like **DOSE**)

Because
With three, you'll live forever,

> (**TRACE**) to **TRACE OVER** a picture of yourself. The drawing would possibly remain forever. 
>  OR, possibly a **TRACE** of you will remain forever.

just two will kill you.

> (**DOSE**) to **OVERDOSE** could cause you to die, depending on the substance.

Thoughts

> Both would be dependent on the word **OVER** being included.

Answer (score 0):

Another funny idea, but I doubt it is correct

> You have a new robot.  Two/three is the number of times you flip the on/off switch.
>  It also works with a computer.

Or maybe

> You ask your doctor: How is my cancer.  Will I survive?
>  If the answers has 2 letters, you die.  If it has 3 you survive.
>  Not sure about the "forever".

Answer (score 0):

Could the answer be

> GOD

With three, you'll live forever,

> GOD -- Living by God's word will give you an eternal life.

just two will kill you.

> OD -- O.D. is to overdose or binge on a substance (usually in reference to hard drugs).